# How to theme D7 search results

Tags: theming, search

The default search results in D7 seem to include details of the node author, date, number of comments as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrnJp.jpg) but I don't want these in my search results.

I have copied search-result.tpl.php and search-results.tpl.php to my theme file. I have added

```
print '<pre>'. check_plain(print_r($info_split, 1)) .'</pre';
```

to search-result.tpl.php. The result is [here](http://maps-310314.click-monkey.net/search/node/valde) ie showing the array with [user] [date] [comment] etc

What do I need to do to exclude author / date / number of comments from the search results? If it involves my theme's search-result.tpl.php what should be the contents of search-result.tpl.php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Copy search-result.tpl.php into your theme folder..

Override above tpl using below code..

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for displaying a single search result.
 *
 * This template renders a single search result and is collected into
 * search-results.tpl.php. This and the parent template are
 * dependent to one another sharing the markup for definition lists.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $url: URL of the result.
 * - $title: Title of the result.
 * - $snippet: A small preview of the result. Does not apply to user searches.
 * - $info: String of all the meta information ready for print. Does not apply
 *   to user searches.
 * - $info_split: Contains same data as $info, split into a keyed array.
 * - $module: The machine-readable name of the module (tab) being searched, such
 *   as "node" or "user".
 * - $title_prefix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that
 *   appears in the template.
 * - $title_suffix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in
 *   the template.
 *
 * Default keys within $info_split:
 * - $info_split['module']: The module that implemented the search query.
 * - $info_split['user']: Author of the node linked to users profile. Depends
 *   on permission.
 * - $info_split['date']: Last update of the node. Short formatted.
 * - $info_split['comment']: Number of comments output as "% comments", %
 *   being the count. Depends on comment.module.
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $classes_array: Array of HTML class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 * - $title_attributes_array: Array of HTML attributes for the title. It is
 *   flattened into a string within the variable $title_attributes.
 * - $content_attributes_array: Array of HTML attributes for the content. It is
 *   flattened into a string within the variable $content_attributes.
 *
 * Since $info_split is keyed, a direct print of the item is possible.
 * This array does not apply to user searches so it is recommended to check
 * for its existence before printing. The default keys of 'type', 'user' and
 * 'date' always exist for node searches. Modules may provide other data.
 * @code
 *   <?php if (isset($info_split['comment'])): ?>
 *     <span class="info-comment">
 *       <?php print $info_split['comment']; ?>
 *     </span>
 *   <?php endif; ?>
 * @endcode
 *
 * To check for all available data within $info_split, use the code below.
 * @code
 *   <?php print '<pre>'. check_plain(print_r($info_split, 1)) .'</pre>'; ?>
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_search_result()
 * @see template_process()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
?>
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

- Clear Cache

Author / date / number of comments from the search results is getting rendered using below code

```
<?php if ($info): ?>
  <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

which we removed from above overridden tpl....

You can also remove it using below function in your theme template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $variables['info'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Pay attention that there're 2 templates relevant to the search results page 'search-result.tpl.php' and 'search-results.tpl.php' :) one for the page and one for each result.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned search-result.tpl.php .. I don't get the point out of above comment... Is it pointed to OP ?

Comment: Yes, and for other readers as well. It may be handy so I thought to mention it.

Comment: +1 for helpful answer. Any idea how to override/theme the default page title and move the search box on the results page? I'd rather have the heading "Search Results" be more prominent.